Action Based scripts not showing
I tried to make my first vr game using unity 3d and when I was following a tutorial and the guy added an Action Based Controller script to the hands, i tried searching it up but nothing came up.
I wanted to attach that script but I just couldn't find it anywhere installed even though i installed everything correctly

It might be that you have to add some package to the unity project. Did the tutorial mention anything in that direction? Or maybe they used a template project, that already has the package installed.
